# Output 1 if count(*) is greater than 0. output 0 otherwise

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+--------------+----------------+
| PersonColumn | AttendedColumn |
+ ------------ + -------------- +
| person1      | attended       |
| person1      | not attended   |
| person2      | not attended   |
| person2      | not attended   |
| person2      | not attended   |
| person3      | attended       |
| person3      | attended       |
+--------------+----------------+
```

so I would like a select statement to output this:

```
+---------+-----+
| person1 |  1  |
| person2 |  0  |
| person3 |  1  |
+---------+-----+
```

that is, output 1 if that person attended at least once. output zero otherwise. I'm using ORACLE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select personcolumn, max(decode(attendedcolumn,'attended',1,0)) from ... group by personcolumn
```

Comment: This is quite smart and short.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation using `CASE` and `GROUP BY`.

For example:

```
select
  personcolumn,
  case when 
    sum(case when attendedcolumn = 'attended' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
    then 1
    else 0 
  end as attended
from t
group by personcolumn
```

Result:

```
 PERSONCOLUMN  ATTENDED 
 ------------- -------- 
 person1       1        
 person2       0        
 person3       1
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b9ac85266099868f1e7bdc8dc70c7af0).

Comment: The `case` expression can be shortened to `sign(count(case ...))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `max()`:

```
select personcolumn,
       max(case when attendedcolumn = 'attended' then 1 else 0 end) 
from t
group by personcolumn;
```